# Richtige Schreibweise von »Fünfziger Jahre«?

Tags: spelling, numbers

Wie werden in einem Text die *Fünfziger Jahre* richtig geschrieben. Ich habe Folgendes gefunden:

- Fünfziger
- 50er
- 50iger

Aber was ist richtig?

Comment: Es reicht nicht für eine Antwort, aber 50iger müsste falsch sein. 50iger = Fünzig+iger geht nicht. Analog dazu, aber korrekt, 50er = Fünzig+er. Ob fünziger bei *Fünfziger Jahre* groß geschrieben werden muss, ist mir nicht klar.

Comment: Ja wahrscheinlich groß und zusammen, also Fünfzigerjahre

Comment: *gelöscht* epsilon und ich haben uns misverstanden

Comment: Ja habe ich, aber ich finde es als Zahl sieht es besser aus. Danke für die Zeit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nach der seit 1996 gültigen Rechtschreibung sind folgende Schreibungen möglich (§ 42 der [Amtlichen Regelung von 2006](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf)):

- 50er Jahre
- 50er-Jahre
- fünfziger Jahre
- Fünfzigerjahre
- Fünfziger-Jahre *(in Verbindung mit § 45)*

Nach der alten Rechtschreibung waren dagegen nur *50er Jahre* und *fünfziger Jahre* korrekt.

*50iger* ist in jeden Fall falsch, da sich bei der Auflösung *fünfzig* + *iger* ergeben würde, also *fünfzigiger*.

Comment: +1 Eine schöne Antwort. Weisst Du auch noch ob *Fünfziger* ohne Jahre korrekt ist? Bsp. *in den Fünzigern waren* oder *Die Fünfziger waren eine ... Zeit*

Comment: Ja, da sind _die Fünfziger_ substantiviert, daher Großschreibung.